# C Program keeps asking for correct number

Tags: c, loops, cs50

The code compiles properly, however everytime I run it, it will not properly run the program.

If I put a # smaller than 23, it still asks me to try again.
If I put the same number in the second time, it works.

If I put a bigger number than 23, it keeps on asking me to try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    printf("What is the height of the pyramid?\n");
    height = get_int();

    do {
        printf("The pyramid cannot be higher than 23 feet!\n");
        printf("Try again!\n");
        printf("What is the height of the pyramid?\n");
        height = get_int(); }
    while (height > 23);

    if (height <= 23) {
        printf("The height of the pyramid is %d feet high!\n", height);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a `do..while()` loop... it will run the body once first before checking the loop condition.  Try a regular `while()` loop instead.

Comment: Don't forget that pyramids can't have negative heights, and zero height pyramids are something of a philosophical conundrum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: but those are the easiest ones to build!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Wouldn't a pyramid with negative height not be simply an upside-down pyramid?

Comment: @Olaf: Have you ever tried building an upside-down Egyptian-size pyramid?  If you search on SO with '`[c] [cs50] pyramid 23`', you'll find that most people think they're required to ensure the user enters a number between 1 and 23, which rules out such esoteric possibilities.  This OP has not noted the lower-bound criterion yet, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have not even built an downside-up pyramid ... ;-) And I don't think I ever will, I'm not Obelix. And "esotheric possibilities" are what makes life interesting (where is Uri Geller if we need him?)

Comment: Geller's admitted he was faking it all along and now makes money from appearance fees

Comment: @M.M: It was James Randi who exposed him. And the lawsuite _was_ interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Loop should be:

```
while (height > 23) {
    printf("The pyramid cannot be higher than 23 feet!\n");
    printf("Try again!\n");
    printf("What is the height of the pyramid?\n");
    height = get_int();
}
```

Using do-while, did 2 things:

1. You Accepted the input first. `height = get_int();`
2. It enters the do-while and without checking if the age is greater than 23. Then asks for input again `height = get_int(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Bandi Kishore's answer, the pyramid's height also can't be less than 1.

```c
                        // ↓this part
while (height > 23 || height < 1) {
    printf("The pyramid should be between 1 and 23 feet high (not %d feet)\n", height);
    printf("Try again!\n");
    printf("What is the height of the pyramid?\n");
    height = get_int();
}
```

CS50 questions should really be at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I completely missed that...fixed now

Comment: Much better.  I'd probably go with `printf("The pyramid should be between 1 and 23 feet high (not %d feet)\n", height);` which is not only a little more succinct (and the acceptable range is presented positively) but also gives feedback on what the program thinks they entered — which can help you enormously when debugging if something's gone wrong with the reading code.  That's a refinement though.